# How to make UIActivityIndicator show on top of UIImageView embedded in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, layout, interface-builder, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an imageView that is embedded inside of a scrollView so as to allow me to pinch and zoom the image in the imageView. I would like however to add an activity indicator to be spinning while the array of images is being loaded.

I put the indicator where I need it in IB, then hooked it up via an IBOutlet. It is spinning when the view loads, and stops at the correct time, the only problem is that it is behind the image and scroll views, not on top where I need it to be.

What can I do to change this and send the indicator to the front? I tried sending to back in IB as well as sending to front, neither have worked...

[image: Is this right?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not putting it inside the UIScrollView. Just sit it on top of the UIScrollView visually, but make the root UIView as its parent. You can drag it around in the Document Viewer (hit Cmd-0) and drag it so that the activity indicator is listed as the same level as the other children of the root UIView. The things at the top of the list are in the "back" so make sure the activity indicator is listed below (but not inside) the UIScrollView.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I went in and did that so that the indicator was a child of the view not the scrollView, and alas, it still is behind the scrollView...I though that should have worked, but it just won't come forward!

Comment: In the Document Window (the one that shows the File's Owner and First Responder objects), grab the UIScrollView and drag it higher so that is listed above the UIActivityIndicator.

Comment: I went in and did that too, and it still won't work. I don't know why not, it just doesn't make sense. I'll just go ahead and move the indicator off to the side for now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Document Window in Interface Builder?

Comment: Hm, you've got a lot more than just one scroll view and one Activity Indicator going on there. :) It looks like it is set up correctly though. Make sure that if you are adding stuff to the view programmatically later on that you aren't putting those new things on top of your activity indicators. You can always add the other things as a subview and then call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.myActivityIndicator];

Comment: Woohoo!!! Kenny you are the man! It was a matter of programmatically ensuring that the indicator view was being sent to the front after adjustments I made in viewDidLoad. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with Apple's PageControl example. ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/PageControl.zip )
For me the solution was to remove the overridden view method in the example, then the z-ordering should work as normal.

```
- (UIView *)view
{
    return self.scrollView;
}
```

Obviously this will only work if your code doesn't depend on it!